# Find the trace of the matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ nonsingular complex matrix whose all eigenvalues are real.Further assume that $A$ satisfy that trace($A^2$)=trace($A^3$)=trace($A^4$).What is the trace of the matrix $A$ ?

Clearly identity matrix is a possible candidate for the matrix $A$ and in this case trace($A$)=trace($A^2$)=trace($A^3$)=trace($A^4$).First I tried to find in case of $2 \times 2$ matrix but I am getting some complicated form.Any hints/ideas?

Comment: For $a\in \mathbb{R}$ what does $a^2=a^3=a^4$ mean?

Comment: $A^n=\prod_{i=1}^n A=V\Sigma^n V^\top$ and $\forall_{n>0}:0^n=0, 1^n=1$. So any matrix $A$ whose eigenvalues are either $1$ or $0$ raised to the power $n$ is equal to $A$. Hence, the trace is the same. But maybe this does not cover all the cases.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I don't get you.What are you asking?

Comment: suppose $A$ is a one by one matrix $A=(a)$ then your assumption implies $a^2=a^3=a^4$ then what can you say about $a$ ??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik i see..$a=1$.but how is this useful?

Comment: I claim that trace of $A$ is $1$... For $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix with eigen values $a,b$ we need to solve $a^2+b^2=a^3+b^3=a^4+b^4$.. As of now i do not have any sensible answer for this but i believe it should be $n$

Comment: I also tried to solve this problem for $2 \times 2$ matrix but i ended up with some complicated form.

Comment: Oh no... I does not mean to say trace of $A$ is $1$ i mean trace of $A$ is $n$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\lambda_i, i=1\dots n$ be the eigenvalues. Then $\rm{trace}(A^m)=\Sigma\lambda_i^m$.

Now try to find two things to apply the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality to so that the LHS and the RHS are both in terms of $\rm{trace}(A^2)$, $\rm{trace}(A^3)$ and $\rm{trace}(A^4)$. Note the equality conditions for CS.

Solution:

> Apply Cauchy-Schwarz to $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ and $(\lambda_1^2,\dots,\lambda_n^2)$ to get $\rm{trace}(A^3)^2\leq\rm{trace}(A^2)\rm{trace}(A^4)$. Since we in fact have equality, we must have $\lambda_i^2=\alpha\lambda_i$ for each $i$ and some fixed $\alpha$. Hence each $\lambda_i$ is zero or $\alpha$. Looking for solutions of this form we find that it works iff $\alpha$ is $1$.

Comment: I got trace(A)=n.No wait.Awesome solution .Thank you !